# Are there any synchronization APIs in Ubuntu Touch yet? (Contacts/Calendar/...)

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

Just wondering if there are any APIs to read/write Contacts/Calendar/Installed Apps/... yet.

I thought about writing an OwnCloud Sync app for the showdown that should be able to synchronize all that across devices, but now I'm not sure if this is even possible on Ubuntu Touch yet. At least I couldn't find any documentation on these cases.

Otherwise it might just be a file-sync (Hello, Ubuntu One?) app that can display the OwnCloud calendar/contacts, but can not integrate into the system as good.

regards,
Adrian

Comment: Hi Adrian, I asked a similar question on the ubuntu touch IRC channel: I wanted to know what syncing protocols  would be supported. I think it was David Planella who sais that the Evolutions data server was going to be implemented in touch so anything that could sync would be okay. That should mean that Webdav and sub-protocols CalDav and CardDav can be used. Great Idea. If you need a hand just let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API you will want to use is the Qt Organizer API.  Currently that only stores things temporarily in memory, but there will soon be a new Evolution Data Server backend that will allow syncing with various services.